# Ipad - Questioning a feature doability

Tags: ios, flutter, ipad, drag-and-drop

I'am currently developing an iPad app using flutter, i come to a feature where the client asked if it doable to implement a feature like on the gmail app on iPad where u can drag a file and drop it into an email as attachement
To be exact the user should be able to drag a file from downloads folder and drop it into the developed app ? is this doable ?

Comment: Yes, it is doable.